# Group SMS in Android by similar Sender Id

Tags: sms, 9.0-pie, productivity

In my country, SMS from different services usually come with a sender id. It mostly look like XXYYYYYY where YYYYYY is 6 digit service name, and XX is kind of a 2 digit random value.

What I want to do is to remove the XX part from the sender id so I can group SMS from same provider YYYYYY in a single conversation.

Is it possible to achieve this in Android somehow?

Comment: Every time you receive a service SMS, you can edit the number manually, or you can try to automate the process. This assumes that you are able to edit the number.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No. I don't know how to edit the number.

Comment: what happens if you assign all these numbers to a single contact? I can far remember on some older sms app it did group by name not by number - if so, you could automatize the contact saving process for incoming messages with Tasker/Macrodroid/etc

Comment: @alecxs These are alphabetical sender id, not phone numbers.